# Is it possible for dramatiq worker to auto shutdown if no messages are present in the queue?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, dramatiq

I am running some dramatiq as kubernetes jobs. The usecase require the pods to shutdown if no messages are in the queue. So what I need is that the dramatiq worker process shutsdown if not messages are in the queue.

Is it possible to do that in dramatiq ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `@dramatiq.actor(max_retries=-1)` decorator, that will result in the worker quitting once it has handled all of the messages in the queue